# Fixed background attachment and custom text

Tags: css, css-position, background-image

I work with some images with fixed background attachment. I would like to place text on some of these images which also takes the position of the fixed background attachment. I tried to do it using   `background-clip: text;` but `background-attachment: fixed` does not work as soon as I combine the two. Does anyone know a work-around?

Thanks!

```css
section {
    width : 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    min-height: 80vh;
    z-index: -1;

}

.with-text {
   background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}


p {
    background-color: white;
}


span {
 font-size: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<section style="background-image: url(http://i54.tinypic.com/4zuxif.jpg)">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
  </p>
</section>
<section class="with-text" style="background-image: url(http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg)">
<span>This text should mask/appear on the background image and not scroll</span>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </p>
</section>
<div>
  <section style="background-image: url(http://i54.tinypic.com/4zuxif.jpg)">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
    </p>
  </section>
  <section style="background-image: url(http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg)">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
  </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please include the code for your attempt so far.

Comment: I added a snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Use css positioning
By making the paragraph position absolute you can put it on image

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work because the absolutely positioned text is still scrollable and does not show the same effect as 'background-attachment: fixed"